# Replace Words from an Array

Tags: php

I want to replace a String with another String from an array.

```
        $replace = array(
        'X' => 'Y'
        );
```

For example:

```
$astring = 'XYZ';
```

And I want to replace all X with Y.

```
$astring = 'YYZ';
```

Comment: Do you seriously not have access to google, or the PHP API? http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `str_replace`. Look at the example in the documentation:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Replace array `$replace` keys with values in string `$astring` :

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $astring);
```